# cocos2d zorder is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

is there any tutorial on zorder for cocos2d?  I have a sprite in a parent layer that always appears behind the sprite in the child layer.  I thought just setting the z would work, but I can see that is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
 Here the z value is the z-order.

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"image.png"];
[self addChild:sprite z:100];
```